# What is the fastest way to brute force a hardware code

Tags: brute-force, physical, physical-access

Where I live, there is a keypad with numbers from 0 to 9 and two letters, A and B.[image: Example of keypad like mine]

Using it I noticed that the code was checked on the last 5 things entered. If I were to try every code on the keypad, I simple answer would be to start from 00000,00001,00002... BBBBB.

However, that would mean that time was wasted in the process.
Consider someone typing 123456789 on the keypad.

In this case, if the door doesn't open, we know that the following codes are invalid:

- 12345
- 23456
- 34567
- 45678
- 56789

What I'm looking for is an algorithm, or at least the name of, to find the path with the fewer key presses.

I'm not looking for a "clever way" of guessing the code, as in look at what digits are dirty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called a [De Bruijn sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence). A pattern that contains all patterns within it.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks. For any future reader, there is a python function you can run to get the full sequence for whatever alphabet and code size!

Comment: Video about this: [This Toy Can Open Any Garage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNodxp9Jy4A)