# Name of 'smart brute force' attack against sequential cipher lock

Tags: attacks, brute-force, terminology

I remember learning about an attack against sequential cipher locks - ones that don't have a 'reset' or 'enter', you just enter digits and as soon as the last n consecutive entries match, the lock opens. So, if the code is '1234', the sequence '32431234' will work just fine.

The attack depends on a specific sequence that appends such digits that the resulting 'tail' of the string is as new as possible.

Let's take for example a 3-digit binary lock. The possible codes are 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111. To try all 8 codes in standard brute force attack, you'd enter 24 digits total.

But instead, entering sequence 0001110100, 10 digits total, you cover all combinations and unlock the lock - generating sequences: 000, 001, 011, 111, 110, 101, 010, 100, each new digit past first 2 generating a new code.

For the good of me, I can't recall the name of the sequence used for this sort of attack.

Comment: looks like a maths problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_optimization

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the fastest way to brute force a hardware code](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/199896/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-brute-force-a-hardware-code)